# How to obtain pandas dataframe from excel sheet which contains vba functions in python

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, openpyxl

I'm struggling to write a code to get the dataframe from an excel file.

That excel file contains basic excel functions and vba functions.

Here is the previous processor I did to do this.

1. Write data on 'sheet1' and save the excel file using openpyxl.

   ```
   wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename, data_only = False)  
   ws = wb['sheet1']
   ...
   <lines>
   ...
   wb.save(filename) 
   wb.close()
   ```
2. Reopen the excel and read data from 'sheet2' which contains bunch of functions.

   ```
   df = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name = 'sheet2')
   ```

Problem is that 'df' contains lots of NaN in which values were by functions.

From googling, I found that because the excel file is not updated and it should be updated by manually or [*win32com.client* code](https://groups.google.com/g/openpyxl-users/c/GbBOnOa8g7Y) for automatic. It shows me the values.. But the automatic code didn't.

3. From another [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.calculateuntilasyncqueriesdone), I added a code to wait the excel update is done.

   ```
   xlapp = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
   xlapp.Visible = False
   wb = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(filename)

   xlapp.CalculateFullRebuild()
   xlapp.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone()

   wb.save(filename)
   wb.close()
   ```

But, nothing workes well.

How can I get updated values in this problem?

Thank you in advance. =)